# Issue performing lint command in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0, lint

I am currently working on a android application which has CI/CD implementation. Everything was working as expected for gradle version 2.0.1. I was able to run ./gradlew clean build command but recently I have upgraded Application to gradle version 3.4.1. 
I am able to run the application on Android Device and Android Emulator. 
However When I am running the same command in terminal build process is getting haulted while doing lint analysis.

I was using android studio version 3.0.1 with gradle version 2.0.1. Application has CI implementation using Jenkins. project was building fine with the configurations when built using ./gradlew clean build.

Recently I have upgraded Android studio to version 3.4.1 and also gradle to 3.4.1 and migrated project from support library to AndroidX.

I am able to upgrade project with some minor warnings. Also able to ran project on Mobile device and on emulator.

However when I try to build project using gradle command then progress is getting stuck while performing lint and goes in infinite loop.
I kept it running for 18 hrs and it kept running.

./gradlew clean build

Project should build fine but somehow lint is not getting completed. Is there any way I can resolve this issue or I can skip lint checks while building the code.

Comment: Checking the issue

Comment: This the answer provided in this link. Hope it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25633285/5773044

Comment: @Zachary I tried but no luck.... is there any possibility that it may happen due to migrating project to androidX ??

Comment: What is the lint error you are getting. check if your debug build(does not use lint) is compiling fine by running command 'gradlew assembleDebug', then compile release build using command 'gradlew assembleRelease'. Also check this command 'gradlew lintfix'

Comment: @RanjanKumar Thanks for the info... I tried and I am able to build successfully using  assembleDebug and assembleRelease command. Then I tried using lintfix command but it is getting stuck on 99% with Transforming artifact play-services-measurement-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3) with AarTransform this line as the last line printed using --info command